# The jump of cadlag process is indistinguishable from the zero process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Let $X$ be adapted and cadlag. If $\Delta X_T1_{T<\infty}=0$ a.s. for each stopping time $T$, then $\Delta X$ is  indistinguishable from the zero process.

Protter proves the above statement by the following arguments:

Define stopping times for each $n$ inductively:

> $T^{n,1} = \inf\{t >0 : |\Delta X_t|>\frac{1}{n}\},$
>
> $T^{n,k}=\inf\{t >T^{n,k-1} : |\Delta X_t|>\frac{1}{n}\}.$

Then $T^{n,k}>T^{n,k-1}$ a.s. on $\{T^{n,k-1}<\infty\}$. Moreover 
$$\{|\Delta X_t|>0\}=\bigcup_{n,k}\{|\Delta X_{T^{n,k}}1_{T^{n,k}<\infty}|>0\}.\tag{1}$$

I am trying to understand this argument. We are trying to establish the LHS of (1) has measure $0$, and using the assumption, it suffices to establish $(1)$.

We know 
$$\{|\Delta X_t|>0\}=\bigcup_{n}\{\omega: \exists t>0, s.t. |\Delta X_t|>\frac{1}{n}\}.\tag{2}$$
Comparing (2) with (1), we know it suffices to show 
$$\{\omega: \exists t>0, s.t. |\Delta X_t|>\frac{1}{n}\}=\bigcup_{k}\{|\Delta X_{T^{n,k}}1_{T^{n,k}<\infty}|>0\}.$$

Then I don't know how to proceed. In particular, I don't know what the state of $\Delta X_{T^{n,k}}$ since $\Delta X_t$ does not have any continuity. Moreover, I don't understand why "$T^{n,k}>T^{n,k-1}$ a.s. on $\{T^{n,k-1}<\infty\}$" is true and how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t_0\in (0,\infty)$. We prove the result on $[0,t_o]$. X is cadlag $\implies\{t:|\Delta X_t|>0\}$ is countable a.s. $$\cup_{n=1}^\infty \{t:|\Delta X_t|>1/n\}=\{t:|\Delta X_t|>0\}.$$  Now, define inductively $T^{n,k}$ as you have done above. The definition of $T^{n,k}$ implies $T^{n,k}>T^{n,k-1}$ a.s. on $\{T^{n,k-1}< \infty \}.$  Protter says these are stopping times as a result of Theorem 4, but $\Delta X$ is not cadlag.  So, thereom 4 specifically does not apply.  He mentions the Debut theorem after that. I consulted Medvegyev's Stochastic Integration Theory for a discussion of the Debut Theorem. $\Delta X$ is progressively measurable since $X$ is cadlag. The Debut theorem implies they are stopping times.
Finally, the last line of the proof follows by noting that the countable union of sets of measure zero has measure zero.

Comment: May I know how do you argue $T^{n,k}> T^{n,k-1}$?

Comment: Fix $\omega$. $T^{n,k}(\omega)=inf\{t>T^{n,k}(\omega):|\Delta X_t(\omega)>1/n\}$.  Its by definition of infimum. Whatever value $T^{n,k}(\omega)$ takes, it must be $\geq T^{n,k-1}(\omega)$ by definition.

Comment: But we need to show they are strictly increasing $>$.

Comment: $\{t:|\Delta X_t|>1/n\}$ is finite $\forall n$. That's why it's strictly increasing.