# Jump of a cadlag process is indistinguishable from the zero process (Protter, Theorem I.7)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

**In Protter's Stochastic Integration, Chapter I, Theorem 7's proof says that if $X$ is adapted and cadlag, then you can use Theorem 4 to say $T(\omega):=\inf\{t>0:|\Delta X_t|>1/n\}$ is a stopping time.** Here $\Delta X_t:=X_t-X_{t-}$ is the jump of the cadlag process.

Although the fact $T(\omega)$ is a stopping time has been proven in many places, none of such proofs use Protter's Theorem 4 e.g. [The jumping times of a càdlàg process are stopping times.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830334/the-jumping-times-of-a-c%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g-process-are-stopping-times) and [The jump of cadlag process is indistinguishable from the zero process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165510/the-jump-of-cadlag-process-is-indistinguishable-from-the-zero-process/2466869).

*Protter's Theorem 4 says that if $\Lambda$ is a closed set, then $T(\omega):=\inf\{t>0:X_t(\omega)\in\Lambda\text{ or } X_{t-}\in\Lambda\}$ is a stopping time.*

Let me paraphrase Protter's proof: "Restrict $X$ to $t\in[0,t_0]$. The set $\{t>0:|\Delta X_t|>1/n\}$ is finite a.s. Therefore, by Theorem 4, $T(\omega)$ [as defined above] is a stopping time." Now, Protter doesn't give more details. **My question is, how does he use Theorem 4?** I need help but first this is an attempt at the proof:

The fact that the set of discontinuities of a cadlag process is finite (when considering only $t\in[0,t_0]$) is very well known. While this is a statement about the time variable $t$, $\Lambda$ in Protter's Theorem 4 concerns the space of $X_t(\omega)$. However, notice that the a.s.-finiteness of $\{t>0:|\Delta X_t|>1/n\}$ implies $\{X_t:|\Delta X_t|>1/n\}$ and $\{X_{t-}:|\Delta X_t|>1/n\}$ are also finite, and hence closed, a.s. However, Theorem 4 requires closedness, not a.s.-closedness. How can I keep going?

Comment: Another idea keeping in mind we're considering only $t\in[0,t_0]$: Because "a.s.-closedness" doesn't do it, how about looking at $\{(t,\omega): |\Delta X_t|>1/n\}$. We can't reasonably expect this new set to be finite because we're now considering all $\omega$ at once. Conjecture: Maybe this set still doesn't have any accumulation points, which would make it closed and we could apply that Theorem 4.

Comment: Why are you so keen on proving the statement using Theorem 4? If you are interested in a detailed proof of the assertion, you can for instance have a look at this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.2479.pdf

Comment: That proof is very similar to the answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830334/the-jumping-times-of-a-c%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g-process-are-stopping-times. To answer your question, I think it would be neat if you could actually derive Theorem 7 from Theorem 4.

Comment: I'd also be interested in how we could use Theorem 4 to show that $T$ is a stopping time. Did you find a solution to this question?